# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected “<” on line 105

Tags: php, joomla

I have a code produced by Joomla that displays an error (see title). I debugged it line by line but don't see any problems. Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2008 - 2009 JoomVision.com. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
 * to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
 * is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
 * other free or open source software licenses.
 * See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
 */

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
include_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'jv_tools.php');

// Javascript
    unset($this->_scripts[$this->baseurl . '/media/system/js/mootools.js']);
    unset($this->_scripts[$this->baseurl . '/media/system/js/caption.js']);

    if($gzip == "true") :
    $this->_scripts = array_merge(array($jvTools->templateurl() . 'js/jv.script.js.php' => 'text/javascript'), $this->_scripts);
     else:
    //$this->_scripts = array_merge(array($jvTools->templateurl() . 'js/jv.collapse.js' => 'text/javascript'), $this->_scripts);
    $this->_scripts = array_merge(array($jvTools->templateurl() . 'js/jv.script.js' => 'text/javascript'), $this->_scripts);
    $this->_scripts = array_merge(array($jvTools->templateurl() . 'js/mootools.js' => 'text/javascript'), $this->_scripts);
    endif;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->baseurl() ; ?>templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->baseurl() ; ?>templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php if($gzip == "true") : ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/template.css.php" type="text/css" />
    <?php else: ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/default.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/template.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/typo.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var baseurl = "<?php echo $jvTools->baseurl() ; ?>";
      var jvpathcolor = '<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/colors/';
      var tmplurl = '<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl();?>';
      var CurrentFontSize = parseInt('<?php echo $jvTools;?>') // ->getParam('jv_font');?>');
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl() ?>js/ie_png.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent ('load', function() {
       ie_png.fix('.png');
    });
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jvTools->templateurl(); ?>/css/ie7.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="bd" class="fs<?php echo $jvTools->getParam('jv_font'); ?> <?php echo $jvTools->getParam('jv_display'); ?> <?php echo $jvTools->getParam('jv_display_style'); ?>">

<div id="jv-wrapper">
    <div id="jv-wrapper-inner">

    <div id="jv-header"  class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <div id="jv-header-inner">

                <div id="jv-logo">
                    <h1 class="png"><a href="<?php echo $jvTools->baseurl() ; ?>" title="<?php echo $jvTools->sitename() ; ?>">
                          <span><?php echo $jvTools->sitename() ; ?></span></a>
                    </h1>
                </div>

                <div class="jv-wrapper">
                    <div id="jv-mainmenu"  >
                        <div id="jv-mainmenu-inner">
                          <?php if($menustyle == 'split' || $menustyle == 'submoo') : ?>
                          <?php $menu->show(0,0); ?>
                          <?php else : ?>
                              <?php $menu->show(); ?>
                          <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <?php if($this->countModules('top')) : ?>   
                        <div id="jv-top" >
                             <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
                        </div>   
                    <?php endif; ?>    
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php if($this->countModules('slideshow')) : ?>
    <div id="jv-userwrap1" class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <div id="jv-userwrap1-inner">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slideshow" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $spotlight = array ('user1','user2','user3','user4');
    $consl = $jvTools->calSpotlight($spotlight,$jvTools->isOP()?100:100,'%');
    if( $consl) :
    ?>
    <div id="jv-userwrap2" class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <div id="jv-userwrap2-inner">               

                <?php if($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>
                <div id="jv-user1" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $consl['user1']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $consl['user1']['width']; ?>;">
                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="jvxhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user2')) : ?>
                <div id="jv-user2" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $consl['user2']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $consl['user2']['width']; ?>;">
                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="jvxhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user3')) : ?>
                <div id="jv-user3" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $consl['user3']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $consl['user3']['width']; ?>;">
                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="jvxhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user4')) : ?>
                <div id="jv-user4" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $consl['user4']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $consl['user4']['width']; ?>;">
                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" style="jvxhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <!-- MAINBODY -->
    <div id="jv-mainbody" class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <!-- CONTAINER -->
            <div id="jv-container<?php echo $jv_width;?>" class="clearfix">

            <div class="jv-mainbody-inner">
            <div class="jv-mainbody-top">
            <div class="jv-mainbody-bottom">
            <div class="jv-mainbody-inset">

                    <div id="jv-content">
                        <div id="jv-content-inner">

                            <?php if($this->countModules('breadcrumb')) : ?>
                                <div id="jv-pathway" class="clearfix">
                                    <div id="jv-pathway-inner">
                                        <strong><?php echo JText::_('You are here:')?></strong> 
                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if($this->countModules('user5')) : ?>
                                <div id="jv-user5" class="clearfix">
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="jvxhtml" />
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <div id="jv-component" class="clearfix">
                                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                            </div>

                           <?php if($this->countModules('user6')) : ?>
                               <div id="jv-user6" class="clearfix">
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="jvxhtml" />
                               </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                           <?php
                            $spotlight = array ('col1','col2','col3');
                            $botsl1 = $jvTools->calSpotlight($spotlight,$jvTools->isOP()?100:99,'%');
                            if( $botsl1 ) :
                            ?>
                            <div id="jv-userwrap3" class="clearfix">
                                    <div id="jv-userwrap3-inner">
                                        <div class="jv-spotlight">

                                            <?php if($this->countModules('col1')) : ?>
                                                <div id="jv-col1" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl1['col1']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl1['col1']['width']; ?>;">
                                                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="col1" style="jvxhtml" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php if($this->countModules('col2')) : ?>
                                                <div id="jv-col2" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl1['col2']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl1['col2']['width']; ?>;">
                                                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="col2" style="jvxhtml" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php if($this->countModules('col3')) : ?>
                                                <div id="jv-col3" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl1['col3']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl1['col3']['width']; ?>;">
                                                    <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="col3" style="jvxhtml" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>


                                        </div>  
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>



                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
                    <div id="jv-right">
                        <div id="jv-right-inner">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="jvxhtml" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <br class="clearfix"/>
            </div>  
                <br class="clearfix"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTAINER -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END MAINBODY -->


    <?php
        $spotlight = array ('user7','user8','user9','user10');
        $botsl2 = $jvTools->calSpotlight($spotlight,$jvTools->isOP()?100:99, '%');
        if( $botsl2 ) :
    ?>
    <div id="jv-userwrap5" class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <div id="jv-userwrap5-inner">
                <div class="jv-spotlight">

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user7')): ?>
                        <div id="jv-user7" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl2['user7']['class']; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $botsl2['user7']['width']; ?>;">
                            <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user7" style="jvxhtml" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user8')) : ?>
                        <div id="jv-user8" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl2['user8']['class']; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $botsl2['user8']['width']; ?>;">
                            <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user8" style="jvxhtml" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user9')) : ?>
                        <div id="jv-user9" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl2['user9']['class']; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $botsl2['user9']['width']; ?>;">
                            <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user9" style="jvxhtml" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->countModules('user10')) : ?>
                        <div id="jv-user10" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl2['user10']['class']; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $botsl2['user10']['width']; ?>;">
                            <div class="jv-box-inside">
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user10" style="jvxhtml" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $spotlight = array ('user11','user12','user13','user14');
    $botsl3 = $jvTools->calSpotlight ($spotlight,$jvTools->isOP()?100:100,'%');
    if( $botsl3 ) :
    ?>
    <div id="jv-userwrap6" class="clearfix">
        <div class="jv-wrapper">
            <div id="jv-userwrap6-inner">
                <?php if($this->countModules('user11')) : ?>
                    <div id="jv-user11" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl3['user11']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl3['user11']['width']; ?>;">
                        <div class="jv-box-inside">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user11" style="jvxhtml" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user12')) : ?>
                    <div id="jv-user12" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl3['user12']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl3['user12']['width']; ?>;">
                        <div class="jv-box-inside">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user12" style="jvxhtml" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user13')) : ?>
                    <div id="jv-user13" class="jv-user jv-box<?php echo $botsl3['user13']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl3['user13']['width']; ?>;">
                        <div class="jv-box-inside">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user13" style="jvxhtml" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('user14')) : ?>
                    <div id="jv-user14" class="jv-user " style="width: <?php echo $botsl3['user14']['width']; ?>;">
                        <div class="jv-box-inside">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user14" style="jvxhtml" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div id="jv-bottom" class="clearfix">
        <div id="jv-bottom-inner">

                <div id="jv-userwrap7" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="jv-wrapper">
                        <div id="jv-userwrap7-inner">

                            <div id="jv-footer">
                                <div id="jv-footer-inner"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" /></div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="jv-copyright">
                                <div id="jv-copyright-inner">
                                    Copyright &copy; 2008 - <?php echo date(Y); ?> <a title="Gashon" href="http://www.omrestaurant.ca">Powered</a>  by GASHON. All rights reserved.
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
</div>

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here are a few observations:

1. in Safari I get a malware warning saying the site may harm my computer, but in IE8 it's fine
2. the path to the code above is /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/templates/jv_cera/index.php, but the path the website displays when it gives me the error is /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/index.php, as in "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/index.php on line 105". Could it be that the error is referring to another website?

Line 105 is the last div in this block of code:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('slideshow')) : ?>
<div id="jv-userwrap1" class="clearfix">
    <div class="jv-wrapper">
        <div id="jv-userwrap1-inner">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slideshow" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div> // <<-- THIS IS LINE 105
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone please help? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Why on Earth would you think the error is in your `om/templates/jv_cera/index.php` file when the error message specifically tells you it's in `om/index.php`?

Comment: hey Phil, that's my line of thought too. ok fine, i will just tell my friend this and help me locate this path then. thank you. i just figured they're the same path since sometimes when i build a site the admin page and the actual page differ slightly like /home/index.php vs. /home/admin/index.php for example. i'll report back tomorrow. bedtime.

Comment: It is most likely coming from an extension that you're using. Uninstall some of the most recent extension if there are any to see if this fixues the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to check whether the error is referring to another website, add a few pointless HTML lines (like ") ABOVE line 105, then run again.  If the error is coming from this page, it the line number should be greater than 105.

Dumb point, but I'm going to mention it anyway: if the error is client side instead of server side, look at the source code that makes it to your browser, not this PHP code.

Comment: hi Brett, I did something like that. I added pointless code above 105 and it still says syntax error on line 105 so i'm beginning to think i'm looking at the wrong code. problem is, i don't know where this code is. it's a Joomla admin site (not mine, my friend's). i know the path - /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/templates/jv_cera/index.php, but when i test the code i get this path error instead - "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/index.php on line 105". in the Joomla admin site, i can't find the path /home/content/93/7079893/html/om/index.php.